# Tabu vertical text overrun and multirow

Tags: multirow, tabu

I am trying to use the tabu environment as I have heard it is sort of the latest and greatest in table making. I am having a weird issue where the text is spilling in the cells below when using multirow. I have included a MWE below (I have not cleaned up the usepackages just in case there are some issues there - I may have things in there that are conflicting or redundant. Some of the things under the TABLE STUFF comment is from other experiments. Essentially I am trying to just find the easiest table solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
%%%%%TABLE STUFF
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \listoftables

    \newpage
    \begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X X X X X}
                \toprule 
    Quantity & Symbol & Defining Equation & SI Unit & Units Definition \\ \midrule
    mass  & m & \multirow{4}{\linewidth}{Basic physical units defined arbitrarily and maintained in standardization laboratories}  & kilogram (kg)  \\
    length  & l &  & meter (m) \\ 
    time  & t &  & second (s)  \\
    current  & I &  & ampere (A)  \\
    force  & F & F = mass * acceleration  & newton (N)  & 1 N = 1 kgms-2 \\
    energy  & E & E = Force * length  & joule (J)  & 1 J = 1 kgm2 s-2 \\
    power  & P & P = E / t  & watt (W)  & 1 W = 1 J/s \\
    frequency  & f, v & number per second  & hertz (Hz)  & 1 Hz = 1 s-1 \\
    charge  & Q & Q = I t  & coulomb (C)  & 1 C = 1 A s \\
    potential  & V & V = E / Q  & volt (V)  & 1 V = 1 J/C \\
    \multirow{2}{*}[-1.05ex]{absorbed dose}  & D & E absorbed from ionizing radiation per kg  & gray (Gy)  & 1 Gy = 1 J / kg \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Gy = 100 rads \\
    exposure  & X & Q liberated by ionizing radiation per kg of air  & C kg-1  & roentgen, R (old) \\
    &  &  &  & 1 R = 2.58x10-4 C/kg \\
    activity  & A & disintigrations of radioactive material per t  & becquerel (Bq)  & 1 Bq = 1 s-1 \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Ci (curie, old) = 3.7x1010 Bq \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabu}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that the `tabu` package is currently unmaintained. (See: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu) I'd recomment `tabularx` instead.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the `hyperref` package should generally (with a few exceptions)  be the last package  in a preamble.

Comment: Will your table become longer than it currently is, so will you need a pagebreak within the table? And would you be willing to change (decrease) the margins of your document?

Comment: For typesetting the si units, you might be interested in the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Thanks for these comments, the table will not increase in length. Thanks for the suggestion on siunitx, I will take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I have added the before missing `\multirow` command and also improved the alignment of the units definitions of "absorbed dose", "activity"  and "exposure". This way, the table can easily fit into a single page without decreasing the margins or the font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pdflscape} % For second example only
%% \usepackage{geometrx} % Used for the third screenshot
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l l L l L}
                \toprule 
    Quantity & Symbol & Defining Equation & SI Unit & Units Definition \\ \midrule
    mass  & m & \multirow{4.5}{=}{Basic physical units defined arbitrarily and maintained in standardization laboratories}  & kilogram (kg)  \\
    length  & l &  & meter (m) \\ 
    time  & t &  & second (s)  \\
    current  & I &  & ampere (A)  \\
    \\
    force  & F & F = mass * acceleration  & newton (\si{\newton})  & \SI{1}{\newton} = \SI{1}{\kilogram\meter\per\square\second} \\ 
    energy  & E & E = Force * length  & joule (\si{\J})  & \SI{1}{\J} = \SI{1}{\kg\square\m\per\square\s} \\
    power  & P & P = E / t  & watt (W)  & 1 W = 1 J/s \\
    frequency  & f, v & number per second  & hertz (Hz)  & 1 Hz = 1 s-1 \\
    charge  & Q & Q = I t  & coulomb (C)  & 1 C = 1 A s \\
    potential  & V & V = E / Q  & volt (V)  & 1 V = 1 J/C \\
    \makecell[tl]{absorbed\\ dose}  & D & E absorbed from ionizing radiation per kg  & gray (Gy)  & 1 Gy = 1 J / kg \newline 1 Gy = 100 rads \\
    exposure  & X & Q liberated by ionizing radiation per kg of air  & C kg-1  & roentgen, R (old) \newline 1 R = 2.58x10-4 C/kg \\
    activity  & A & disintigrations of radioactive material per t  & becquerel (Bq)  & 1 Bq = 1 s-1 \newline 1 Ci (curie, old) = 3.7x1010 Bq\\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}}

    \end{document}
```

---

**Original answer:**

Here are three versions of your table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pdflscape} % For second example only
%% \usepackage{geometrx} % Used for the third screenshot
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l l L l L}
                \toprule 
    Quantity & Symbol & Defining Equation & SI Unit & Units Definition \\ \midrule
    mass  & m & Basic physical units defined arbitrarily and maintained in standardization laboratories  & kilogram (kg)  \\
    length  & l &  & meter (m) \\ 
    time  & t &  & second (s)  \\
    current  & I &  & ampere (A)  \\
    force  & F & F = mass * acceleration  & newton (\si{\newton})  & \SI{1}{\newton} = \SI{1}{\kilogram\meter\per\square\second} \\ 
    energy  & E & E = Force * length  & joule (\si{\J})  & \SI{1}{\J} = \SI{1}{\kg\square\m\per\square\s} \\
    power  & P & P = E / t  & watt (W)  & 1 W = 1 J/s \\
    frequency  & f, v & number per second  & hertz (Hz)  & 1 Hz = 1 s-1 \\
    charge  & Q & Q = I t  & coulomb (C)  & 1 C = 1 A s \\
    potential  & V & V = E / Q  & volt (V)  & 1 V = 1 J/C \\
    \makecell[tl]{absorbed\\ dose}  & D & E absorbed from ionizing radiation per kg  & gray (Gy)  & 1 Gy = 1 J / kg \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Gy = 100 rads \\
    exposure  & X & Q liberated by ionizing radiation per kg of air  & C kg-1  & roentgen, R (old) \\
    &  &  &  & 1 R = 2.58x10-4 C/kg \\
    activity  & A & disintigrations of radioactive material per t  & becquerel (Bq)  & 1 Bq = 1 s-1 \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Ci (curie, old) = 3.7x1010 Bq \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}}


\begin{landscape}
\noindent
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l l L l l}
                \toprule 
    Quantity & Symbol & Defining Equation & SI Unit & Units Definition \\ \midrule
    mass  & m & Basic physical units defined arbitrarily and maintained in standardization laboratories  & kilogram (kg)  \\
    length  & l &  & meter (m) \\ 
    time  & t &  & second (s)  \\
    current  & I &  & ampere (A)  \\
    force  & F & F = mass * acceleration  & newton (\si{\newton})  & \SI{1}{\newton} = \SI{1}{\kilogram\meter\per\square\second} \\ 
    energy  & E & E = Force * length  & joule (\si{\J})  & \SI{1}{\J} = \SI{1}{\kg\square\m\per\square\s} \\
    power  & P & P = E / t  & watt (W)  & 1 W = 1 J/s \\
    frequency  & f, v & number per second  & hertz (Hz)  & 1 Hz = 1 s-1 \\
    charge  & Q & Q = I t  & coulomb (C)  & 1 C = 1 A s \\
    potential  & V & V = E / Q  & volt (V)  & 1 V = 1 J/C \\
    \makecell[tl]{absorbed\\ dose}  & D & E absorbed from ionizing radiation per kg  & gray (Gy)  & 1 Gy = 1 J / kg \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Gy = 100 rads \\
    exposure  & X & Q liberated by ionizing radiation per kg of air  & C kg-1  & roentgen, R (old) \\
    &  &  &  & 1 R = 2.58x10-4 C/kg \\
    activity  & A & disintigrations of radioactive material per t  & becquerel (Bq)  & 1 Bq = 1 s-1 \\
    &  &  &  & 1 Ci (curie, old) = 3.7x1010 Bq \\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

If your table gets longer and you need a pagebreak within the table, I'd suggest to replace `tabularx` with `xltabular`.

Comment: Hi sorry, all 3 versions of that table do not have a multirow for the long sentence at the top which is the problem I am trying to overcome.

Comment: @thatguy14: Sorry, I removed the `multirow` command because I didn't get its purpose. I just now came to realize that you wanted the text in the third column to continue for mass, lenght, tie and current. I will add an update in a minute.

Comment: @thatguy14: I have added an update.

Answer (score 0):

Leandriis comments made me realize that this is due to the fact that the table could not extend past 1 page and this overrun was due to this (i.e., the table was too big for 1 page so it compressed it). This was fixed by either changing the font size or increasing the margins